# Padrino mongoid logging

Tags: mongodb, logging, mongoid, padrino

How to view all queries in console to mongodb?

`Mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout)`

does not help

**database.rb**

```
host = 'localhost'
port = Mongo::Connection::DEFAULT_PORT
database_name = case Padrino.env
  when :development then 'blog_development'
  when :production  then 'blog_production'
  when :test        then 'blog_test'
end
Mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
Mongoid.database = Mongo::Connection.new(host, port).db(database_name)
```

Comment: For future visitors, if you want beautiful colored logging similar to active record, you might want to look at [the mongo beautiful logger gem](https://github.com/redline-gh/mongo_beautiful_logger/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this: `Mongoid.logger = Padrino.logger`

Or better:

```
Mongo::Connection.new(host, 27017, :logger => Padrino.logger).db(name)
```

Comment: mmm are you sure that this is the only necessary thing to configure logging in mongoid? Using same way in mongomapper works like a charm.